# Laravel request showing '::1' for IP address

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to find the user's IP address in Laravel. [`request->ip()`](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_ip) seems like it would do the job, but that just returns `::1`. I also tried `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, but get the same; `$_SERVER` returns the following for me:

```
array:24 [▼
  "DOCUMENT_ROOT" => "xxx"
  "REMOTE_ADDR" => "::1"
  "REMOTE_PORT" => "51995"
  "SERVER_SOFTWARE" => "PHP 5.5.32 Development Server"
  ...
]
```

The `REMOTE_ADDR` is always `::1` for me. I've tried 3 different WiFi networks. Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: In the `$_SERVER` associative array, there isn't any forwarding, so I wouldn't expect localhost.

### Edit

I understand that this is my local machine. Is there a way to stub that out in testing so I can make assertions on it (e.g., that it matches a certain format)?

Comment: `::1` is `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` in IPv6

Comment: upload your project to a server and then check, it will show your external IP address.

Comment: " stub that out in testing so I can make assertions on it " what does this mean?

Comment: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

Comment: The `ip()` method and that on which it relies are already unit tested as part of Laravel and Symfony. If you just want to ensure your method calls the IP function you can use something like `Request::shouldReceive('ip')->once()->andReturn('::1')`

Comment: If you want to test that the IP matches a certain format, make a means by which to validate it, and pass in expected passes and failures, then assert that `ip` gets called/passed to your validation. The testing on your validation and the existing testing on `ip()` should suffice.

Answer (score 9):

I assume you're running your website on the same server / computer you're making the request.

`::1` is `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` in IPv6 (your current netcard address).

So if you put your website on a distant server, you'll get the user IP address.

I guess you can choose the IPv4 or IPv6 display in your config file.

Answer (score 1):

It happens, if your project located on localhost, upload to server.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because $_SERVER['REMODE_ADDR'] is only defined when there's, well, a remote address, i.e. somebody requests your page from a browser. With cron the script is executed locally and the setting may be empty. If it breaks your code, try setting it yourself at the start of the script:

```
if( !isset($_SERVER['REMODE_ADDR']) ) {
   $_SERVER['REMODE_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1';
}
```

more here
[Undefined REMOTE_ADDR when using Cron Jobs - Backpack for Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58682053/undefined-remote-addr-when-using-cron-jobs-backpack-for-laravel)