# Undefined REMOTE_ADDR when using Cron Jobs - Backpack for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

Has anyone faced an issue when using Cron Jobs with Backpack for Laravel?
I am getting **"Undefined index: 'REMOTE_ADDR' at LicenseCheck.php:22"** (that's a Backpack file).
It seems like when using a cron job, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] in LicenseCheck.php is not defined. Any thoughts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362690/remote-addr-empty-not-included-in-server-array covers this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because `$_SERVER['REMODE_ADDR']` is only defined when there's, well, a remote address, i.e. somebody requests your page from a browser. With cron the script is executed locally and the setting may be empty. 
If it breaks your code, try setting it yourself at the start of the script:

```
if( !isset($_SERVER['REMODE_ADDR']) ) {
   $_SERVER['REMODE_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1';
}
```

Comment: Tried that, but no success. I "fixed" it by comment that line out, but since the file is located in the vendor folder, I will face the same issue again if I run composer update.

Comment: Instead of changing that in the vendor folder, you could change that before the package runs, like at index.php. Then composer update wouldn't break it.

Comment: That's right! Didn't think about placing that in index.php. That has saved the problem. Thanks!